# How to extend Ranorex for a native UI toolkit?

Tags: c++, winapi, ranorex

In our company we use a native win32 UI framework written in C++. There are several controlls where Ranorex Spy doesn't "see" any useful information for identification or verification.

Is there some API in Ranorex that can be used to make it compatible with such a framework?

Changing the framework to make it more Ranorex-friendly is not going to happen (company politics).

Comment: If the docs don't say anything about such a case, I'd ask Ranorex's support.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue where the application I'm testing has a list box, with items in it, however Ranorex was not picking up anything beyond the list box. In fact, it actually recognized it as a plain 'Element', rather than a list box.

To fix, try this...

Right click the object (in my case it was the Element)and click "Add process name to GDI capture list".

In my case, it added a bunch of text objects under the Element, which enabled me to actually "See" the info I needed.

Comment: This works for some, but not all our custom controlls. And I considder it as a hack personally, since it picks up any text or image the GDI API knows about. In our case we have a custom ribbon controll. GDI capture works to find the individual button texts and click on them. But we still can't validate if a button is active or no, since Ranorex don't see the button.